# Use same monitor setup at every docking station

Tags: laptop, powershell, multiple-monitors

My company moved to a new office with about 400 'freefloating' desks. Every morning, I arrive, find a free spot, connect my laptop, and start working. Each desk has an identical set-up, with a big monitor and a docking station.

Now, every time I sit down at a desk I haven't sat at before, I need to configure the monitor set-up:

1. Extend the display
2. Make the external monitor the main one
3. Position the laptop screen to the left of the external one, with their bottom edges alligned.

It's not a *lot* of work, but do it every single day for a few weeks and you too will want to automate it.

**Is there a small script I could use to get these settings done?**

I found `DisplaySwitch.exe` but that only does the first step.

Comment: You could probably write one. We are not a scriptwriting service tho. But if you decide to write one and get stuck somewhere SO may be able to help. Programming and software development is offtopic here.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll take my question to stack overflow